# Why excel is not working correctly when comparing date with "<=" operator?

Tags: excel, sumifs, date-comparison

I'm using a sumif formula with condition that when the date is smaller or equal to the specific date, it will sum up the value. My formula:
[image]

I expect the answer will be summing up all values in column A but turns out only sum up the first row
The result:

[image]

What is weird is that when I can the sign to "=", the formula can add up all the date in column B matching the dates but can't add up the number when I use "<=" operator

[image]

Comment: Are your dates really in date format? They are aligned to the left, so I suspect they are just text values. So comparison makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

The DATEVALUE function is not needed. Just get remove it:

```
=SUMIFS($G:$G,$E:$E,"<="&$E2)
```

[image]

EDIT: In response to updated question

I believe the problem is how Excel is interpreting your dates. Any date comparisons will not work as expected if Excel is treating the value in the cell as text instead of Dates (or numbers).

To check this, you can add a temporary column with the formula:

```
=ISTEXT($E2)
```

Then drag down. If any return true, these are not being interpreted as dates by excel.

Here is an example. The "dates" highlighted in yellow are entered as text values.

[image]

To ensure the values ARE interpreted as dates, you can add another temporary column with this formula:

```
=$E2+0
```

Then copy the the temporary column into your date column "as values".
You can do this by copying the temporary column, then right clicking and selecting this icon:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Ensure that your date column is formatted as "Short Date".
Finally, you can delete any temporary columns.

Comment: My formula is not having the DATEVALUE function at the beginning but it's not working, so I tried to add that in. and the result is the same

Comment: How is it not working? Have you entered the exact same formula that is shown to be working in my screenshot?

Comment: You can refer to my attached photo "Weird Case" for the formula I typed under "show formulas" mode. Will it be a data format issue? The format of my Column E is all in date